# Dice roll, payoff, entry fee

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A player rolls two dice. Then he is told that there is an entry fee. And that the number of dollars he wins is equal to the number of dots on the dice.
The number of dots on the dice he rolled is divisible by $3$.

What should the entry fee be in order for the game to be profitable to the player?

So the possible results of the roll are $3,6,9,12$ with probabilities $P(S_2 = 3) = \frac{2}{36}$, $P(S_2 = 6) = \frac{5}{36}$, $P(S_2 = 9) = \frac{4}{36}$, $P(S_2 = 12) = \frac{1}{36}$.

Now I suppose I should calculate expected values. But I am not sure whether I should condition the probability on the event of the number being divisible by three or not.

Could you tell me if I am right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if it is already known that his total is divisible by 3, then those 4 probabilities must sum to 1 while still being in the same proportion 2:5:4:1.  Right now they sum to 1/3, so multiply them by 3.

Comment: Thank you! So the expected value is $3 \cdot 1/6 + 6 \cdot 5/12 + 9 \cdot 1/3 + 12 \cdot 1/12 = 7$.

Comment: Could you tell me what the fee should be?

Comment: Same as the EV you computed to make the game fair (0 EV).  The fee subtracts from the EV, so a 7 dollar fee makes it a break-even game.

Comment: Actually this assumes these rules are in place before you threw the dice.  If not, I wouldn't just fork over 7 bucks since the guy may only be offering this when I threw a 3 or 6!

Comment: So before we throw the dice the fee is $7$ dollars, right? And this makes the game fair if the number of dots is divisible by $3$. But in general the fee should be equal to the expected value of $X_1+X_2$ for $X_i$ = the number of dots on the $i$-th die?

Comment: If the rules are stated before the game that he has to reveal that you rolled a multiple of 3 and then give you the option to pay the fee (as your problem stated), then when that happens you can pay 7 dollars for a fair game.  If you were paying a fee for any total, 7 dollars is still the right amount for a fair game.  That's because the average of each die is 3.5, and so the average sum is 3.5 + 3.5 = 7.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, the expected value is still $7$ - it was a stupid question. Thanks for all your help, again!